# Bootstrap Modal not loading after page reloads

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Bootstrap Modal does not load after page has been refreshed certain times.
After that, the modal will only show up when I open the page in incognito.
Does anyone have any fix for this bug?
You can go to the actual site to see for yourself: http://www.petalandco.com.au/

js:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var hiddenmodal = getCookie('hiddenmodal');
        if (hiddenmodal == "") {
            jQuery('#popupNewsletterModal').modal('show');
        }
    }, 100);
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="popupNewsletterModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="width:679px;height:439px;">
    <div class="modal-content" style="<?php echo ($style);?>">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0);top:0px;">
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="color:#000;font-size:40px;">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <div class="widget popupnewsletter-widget heading__center">
```

Comment: the condition `hiddenmodal == ""` is not true then , try to display `hiddenmodal` to check its value

Comment: @Neji Soltani what do you mean by log? display its value?

Comment: yes i mean displaying it in order to see if the condition return true or false

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle or edit it as a code sample so that we can see the result.

Comment: @mrquad you can go to the site and try it yourself: http://www.petalandco.com.au/

Comment: @Neo Soltani i am quite new in Javascript, but if u input console.log();, it will show up in dev mode's console section, right? if so, then it shows just empty for me which makes the if condition, true right?

Comment: @Neo Soltani in incognito the console.log() is empty while on a normal window it display 1